# How to differentiate between a realtime and non-realtime interrupt during processing?

Tags: cloud, virtualization, interrupt, kvm

How to differentiate between a realtime and non-realtime interrupt during course of a running process, without user's input?
I am writing an application for virtual interrupt handling in cloud and I need my algorithm to determine the kind of interrupt to enable real time processing.

I have already taken into account a timer to time-off the algorithm to maintain real time operability. Is it possible somehow to determine from the interrupt's data structure to determine its urgency?